# Dini's theorem, under which conditions?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation

According to **Dini's theorem**:

> If $X$ is a compact topological space, and $\{ f_n \}$ is a monotonically
>   increasing sequence (meaning $f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $n$ and $x$) of
>   continuous real-valued functions on $X$ which converges pointwise to a
>   continuous function $f$, then the convergence is uniform.
>
> The same conclusion holds if $\{ f_n \}$ is monotonically decreasing
>   instead of increasing.

(Note: I have proven both cases)

**1)** If for every $n$ $\{f_n(x0)\}$ is monotonic but for some values of $n$ it's monotonically decreasing and for other it's monotonically decreasing.
for example; for all even values it is increasing and for non-even values it is decreasing.

How could I prove that Dini's theorem is effective in this case?
**In other words**, how to prove that the convergence is uniform

**2)** Can I require that {fn} is monotonic starting from a specific index that's related to x? for example; what if {fn} is monotonic when n>7x?

**Note:** I already got an answer to no. 2 thanks to @Robert

Answer (score 2):

(1) Do you mean a sequence $f_n$ such that for each $n$, either $f_{n+1} \ge f_n$ everywhere or $f_{n+1} \le f_n$ everywhere?

Let $g_n$ be a sequence of functions on $X$ with $g_n > 0$ and $g_n \to 0$ pointwise but not uniformly on $X$, take $f_{2n}(x) = g_n(x)$ and $f_{2n+1}(x) = -g_n(x)$.  Then $f_{n+1} < f_n$ if $n$ is even and $f_{n+1} > f_n$ if $n$ is odd, and $f_n \to 0$ pointwise but not uniformly.

EDIT: OK, it seems that wasn't what you meant.  If $f_n$ is monotonically decreasing on $A \subset X$ and monotonically increasing on $B \subset X$, with $A \cup B = X$, note that we can take $A$ and $B$ to be compact (since  $\{x \in X: f_{n+1}(x) \le f_n(x)\}$ and  $\{x \in X: f_{n+1}(x) \ge f_n(x)\}$ are closed).  Thus $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $A$ and converges uniformly to $f$ on $B$, and therefore converges uniformly to $f$ on $A \cup B = X$.

(2) Consider a sequence of triangular bump functions on $[0,1]$

$$ f_n(x) = \cases{n x & if $0 \le x \le 1/n$ \cr
                   2 - nx & if $1/n \le x \le 2/n$ \cr
                   0 & if $x \ge 2/n$\cr}
$$
Thus for any $x > 0$, $f_{n+1}(x) \le f_n(x)$ when $n \ge 1/x$,
while $f_{n+1}(0) \le f_n(0)$ for all $n$.  $f_n \to 0$ pointwise but not uniformly.